# Confused about the direction of motion of a light ray moving radially towards a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

In one of susskind lectures, he sets $d \tau ^2=0$ in the Schwarzschild metric to calculate $dr/dt$, and gets the equation

$$(1-GM/r)^2=(dr/dt)^2$$

or

$$  \pm(1-GM/r)=dr/dt                $$

He said that the positive solution sign corresponds to an outgoing light ray, and the negative solution to a ray moving towards the center. Both solutions have c=0 at the horizon. He only analyzed the  outgoing ray, which changed direction inside the horizon and actually moves towards the center. But should not also predict that an inward light ray inside a black home will move towards the horizon? as $dr/dt$ becomes positive there (is not the initial negative sign of $-(1-GM/r)$  cancelled by the negative sign of $(1-GM/r)$ itself inside the black hole? (he did not talk about this example).

Comment: That question was already answered at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/784268/lightlike-vector-in-schwarschild-metric/784272#784272 and is explained in detail at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_2vnb_eVGE&list=PLJHszsWbB6hqlw73QjgZcFh4DrkQLSCQa&index=39&t=540s

Comment: @Yukterez Thanks, I am going to check those links

Comment: @Yukterez but can you give a short argument about why the equations above fail? what part of the argument is wrong or does not apply in the equations above and why? thanks

Comment: The ingoing lightrays at r<rs do move toward r=rs with increasing coordinate time t while the outgoing ones move toward r=0, but the affine parameter of both photons (or in case of particle their proper time τ) increases in direction of r=0. The coordinate time t is unphysical at r<rs though since that coordinates use stationary clocks which can't exist at r<rs, therefore we rather use Raindrop or Finkelstein coordinates, see [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Schwarzschild-Droste-Green-Lightcones.png#Photon_Worldlines_(v=%C2%B11,_E=%E2%88%9A[1-2/r%E2%82%80])) for a comparison.

Comment: @Yukterez Thanks!

Comment: @Yukterez Your comment above is misleading, because the Schwarzschild coordinate $t$ does not measure time inside the horizon. It measures space, is not “unphysical”, and has nothing to do with “stationary clocks” there. “*we rather use Raindrop or Finkelstein coordinates*” - No, “we” don’t. It is just your own personal preference. These coordinates are misleading and easily lead to wrong conclusions. For example, on your animations, the Schwarzschild singularity is pictured as a “point”, as if a black hole has a “center”, while this singularity is an infinitely long spacelike line along $t$.

Comment: @safesphere wrote: *»No, “we” don’t [use Raindrop or Finkelstein coordinates]«* - most people do, you are one of the few exceptions that don't. --- safesphere wrote: »*These coordinates are misleading and easily lead to wrong conclusions*« - it's the other way around, that's what most people say about the classic Schwarzschild Droste coordinates when it comes to paths crossing the horizon. Raindrop and Finkelstein were invented to resolve that problem by giving the local clocks a physically reasonable velocity v=√[gₜᵣgᵗʳ] which must be smaller than c outside, c at he horizon and larger inside.

Comment: @safesphere wrote: *»Yes, ironic, since science is never defined by “most people”«* - with "most people" I don't mean the fans of Justin Bieber or Kim Kardashian, I refer to the general consensus in the field. You can google that easily since almost every article and video about that coordinates tells you what they're for, while the papers that claim the coordinate singularity is real are outdated since almost a 100 years.

Comment: @safesphere - that's the regular projection of the coordinates, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_singularity): *»in a non-rotating black hole the singularity occurs at a single point in the model coordinates, called a "point singularity"«*, and if any it would rather be a surface, not a line, see [here](http://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/talks/insidebh/schwJoopath.html), but if you know of an animation where it is depicted as a line let me know the link